# How do I set the default View in MS Publisher to Page Width?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-publisher

Every time I open my .PUB, it defaults to Normal View when I want Page Width. Is there a way to change the document's default view, or even better, MS Publisher's default view, to Page Width?

Specs:

- Microsoft Publisher 2010
- Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2010
- Windows 7 Professional x64

Answer (score -1):

Try giving the **Default Zoom Add-in** a go and see if that works. You can download it from [here](http://ed.mvps.org/Static.aspx?=Publisher/add-ins).

> This add-in is also a snap to use - simply set the options under View
> Default Zoom, and they will be reset for you every time you start a new document.
>
> Known Issues:
>
> - The add-in will fail to set the zoom properly when the Catalog is disabled on startup.
> - The add-in will only work on the first-opened document. i.e. If you are working on a Publisher document and click New, then the zoom
>   may/will not be set.

Comment: This add on doesnt work with Microsoft Publisher 2010